# Securing post-login pages from unauthorized access - jQuery + Java Spring

Tags: jquery, spring, jwt

Im building a web app which has some features available only after logging in. Its build in HTML with jQuery and I'm building authorization with JWT. It's easy to refuse sending response from backend if user doesn't send valid token, but what about accessing pages which should be available only after login? Let's say i have a page

```
foobar.com/panel.html
```

which should be available only after login. What if someone just go to this address without logging in? He won't be able to send any request to backend, but he will see whole page. How to redirect him to main page or to login page? I know how to do it in jquery or js but what if user has js turned off in his browser? Shall I send whole HTML page from backend in response only if he provides me a token and redirect him if not? I don't like this solution becouse I wanted to separate frontend and backend as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security principles are simple:
You provide information of

- what are and aren't protected pages
- which protected pages can be accessed by which user roles
- what is the login page
- what is the logout url
- what is authentication failure url
- ...

and then Spring Security does everything behind the scene.
please check out this page
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/